# get bts info from context of onReceive

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I use onRecive function to get sms in one BroadcastReceiver class

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
```

I want get neighbor bts provider in this function with this code

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

List<NeighboringCellInfo> NeighboringList = telephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();

String retStr="";
for (int i = 0; i < NeighboringList.size(); i++) { 
   int cid = NeighboringList.get(i).getCid();
   int lac = NeighboringList.get(i).getLac();                    
}
```

this code can not get any bts ,But when I using it in one activity is working properly and find all neighbor bts.

I think the problem is context type , but I don't know how solve it. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Create a Class like this:

```
public class Setting extends Application {

public static Context context;


public static AlarmManager alarmManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();

   }
}
```

and then use this context Where ever you need to set it Like this:

```
Setting.context;
```